# convert simple c# method to jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

```
double myNumber;

myNumber.ToString("0.:#0").Replace(".", "");
```

Could someone tell me the equivalent jquery function?

Sorry not to good with jquery.

Thanks,

Comment: Please keep in mind that this is a Question & Answer site, and not a code writing service, even if it is just two lines.

Comment: For those not familiar with C#, what does it do?

Comment: @Bobby: Agreed. @Csharper: Instead of having us do this, write out what it does in C# and use the jquery (or even just JS) documentation to guide you through the code. Then, if you get stuck, post the code you have and we can help.

Comment: PS I'm fairly sure that you can accomplish this task with native JavaScript - there's no need for jQuery here.

Comment: This is the closest I could find: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-utils/wiki/StringFormat#Formatting the format syntax is different from the C# one but you should be able to achieve same results.

Comment: @Booby - Your right, I appologies for my laziness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery is not necessary for this and actually doesn't have number formatting methods (unless you use a plugin).

I would do it like this just using native JavaScript:

```
var myNumber;

myNumber.toFixed(2).replace(".", ":");
```

The `toFixed()` method allows you to specify the number digits after the decimal place.

Comment: I think the ".toString()" is redundant... `.toFixed(x)` returns a String.  http://www.devguru.com/technologies/javascript/17443.asp

Comment: @scunliffe Good point. I didn't realize that. I removed it from the code.